# Does anyone have any T4 example Templates that can be used to generate a Webservice?

Tags: web-services, t4

Does anyone have any T4 example Templates (or links to same) that can be used to generate a Webservice?

I'm thinking of the fact that I guess the Webservice is not just the Vb or Cs field but also requires an appropriate asmx file.

I'm really not sure how to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oleg Sych: How to generate multiple outputs from single T4 template](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template/); create another method that generates your asmx - should be pretty simple, as it's one line - and renders it to a file.

[T4 Toolbox](http://www.codeplex.com/t4toolbox) also has some methods that are helpful for this.  Oleg Sych's site also has other articles that will guide you through it, particularly these:

- [T4 Toolbox](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/08/t4-toolbox/)
- [Creating a complex code generator](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-creating-complex-code-generators/)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Web Service Software Factory](http://www.codeplex.com/servicefactory) will do what you need right out of the box. As I understand, it generates code with T4 templates you can extend.